# How to retrieve object name by providing object id?

Tags: rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have run pr2_pick_and_place_demos and got object_id for a cup.

After retrieving the object id, I want to know the name of the detected object in data base, I found that there's a service handling this kind of request(which is stated [here.](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/household_objects_database_msgs/html/srv/GetModelDescription.html))

But I cannot find this service with "rosservice list"(obviously it is not launched), I want to ask if anyone knows how to start this service so that I can request the name with this snippet of code.

### Edit:

(The code below works if you create a package named getObjectName and depend this package on household_objects_database_msgs)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib; 
roslib.load_manifest('getObjectName') #For loading srv in household_objects_database_msgs 

import rospy
from household_objects_database_msgs.srv import *

rospy.wait_for_service('/objects_database_node/get_model_description')
get_object_name=rospy.ServiceProxy('objects_database_node/get_model_description',GetModelDescription)
resp = get_object_name(18744) #Object id is 18744
print resp
```

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46263/how-to-retrieve-object-name-by-providing-object-id?/) by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1371 on 2012-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The services for dealing with the PR2 object database are provided by the node [household_objects_database](http://www.ros.org/wiki/household_objects_database). Once set up correctly, it will provide a bunch of services, including:

- /objects_database_node/get_model_list
- /objects_database_node/get_model_description
- /objects_database_node/get_model_mesh

`rosservice list | grep objects_database_node` should give you a complete list.

Note that you'll have to set up a Postgre SQL server and import the object database.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2